# Compare values for a specific day and show last data in the table

Tags: php, laravel

If there are multiple records that match the date, how sum them and display them in the last place? If duplicate date exist, then just show a last record's result value with sum of duplicated result values.
The maximum per day possible time is 8 hours.

Language: PHP in Laravel 5.7

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `->select('*', 'SUM(total) as sumtotal')` `->groupBy('date')` to the eloquent query.